# Trying to get the CRC32 hash for a hex string extracted from an xml file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I have a form where I'm extracting some text and hex data from elements in an xml file, this is working great for the text and hex so far but I am trying to calculate the CRC32 for a string of hex data that's in a label.text control.
I'm getting a result in the label but the hex value is that of a string (i'm using an online CRC32 generator to compare the results) when I select the input data to bytes I get the correct checksum that matches the checksum in the original xml file, when I select string in the online form I get the same value that appears on my form.

How can I send the label.text data to the crc32 class in the right format to get the same answer as the online form when bytes is selected, I've tried converting to hex but I just can't seem to get it to work.

This is the hex (Motorola format) I want the CRC32 for
`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`

This is the CRC32 HEX result I need
`6889CDCF`

Here is the Crc32 code I got from this forum: -

```
Public Class Crc32
     Shared table As UInteger()

     Shared Sub New()
         Dim poly As UInteger = &Hedb88320UI
         table = New UInteger(255) {}
         Dim temp As UInteger = 0
         For i As UInteger = 0 To table.Length - 1
             temp = i
             For j As Integer = 8 To 1 Step -1
                 If (temp And 1) = 1 Then
                     temp = CUInt((temp >> 1) Xor poly)
                 Else
                     temp >>= 1
                 End If
             Next
             table(i) = temp
         Next
     End Sub

     Public Shared Function ComputeChecksum(bytes As Byte()) As UInteger
         Dim crc As UInteger = &HFFFFFFFFUI
         For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
             Dim index As Byte = CByte(((crc) And &HFF) Xor bytes(i))
             crc = CUInt((crc >> 8) Xor table(index))
         Next
         Return Not crc
     End Function
 End Class
```

Here is the code I'm using

```
If xmlR.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xmlR.Name = "DATEN" Then
    HexData = xmlR.ReadElementContentAsString
    LblRawhex.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(HexData, 8)
    LblDataNmeHex.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(HexData, 9, 24)
    TxtFullHex.Text = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(HexData, Len(HexData) - 8)
    LblCRC.Text = Hex(Crc32.ComputeChecksum(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TxtFullHex.Text)))
    'LblCRC.Text = Crc32.ComputeChecksum(Hex(TxtFullHex.Text))
End If
```

This is the online CRC32 generator and the result is what I'm trying to get in my form.

[Online CRC result for Byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpJmY.png)

but I get this result in my VB form

[Online CRC result for string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvOUx.png)

I realise it's probably down to my lack of understanding in data types as I'm only a self taught amateur!

Thanks for any help.

I've tried to do type conversion to see if I can send in a byte format but it doesn't help

Comment: You don't want to be calling Encoding.GetBytes. That would be if you had text that represented words. In this case, you have hexadecimal data that represents bytes. You should be calling Convert.ToByte for each pair of hex digits and then feeding the resulting Bytes in to your CRC algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jmcihinney already mentioned, convert the string to a byte array first. I made a little test program with your code fragments and it results in the expected CRC:

```
Imports System

Module Program

    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim testString As String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
        Dim byteArray As Byte() = Hex.ToByteArray(testString)
        Dim result As UInt32 = Crc32.ComputeChecksum(byteArray)
        Dim stringResult As String = result.ToString("X8") '6889CDCF
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Hex

    Public Shared Function ToByteArray(hexString As String) As Byte()
        If (hexString Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(hexString))
        hexString = hexString.Trim()
        If (hexString.Length Mod 2) = 1 Then Throw New ArgumentException($"Invalid hex string: an even number of characters expected! Actual: {hexString.Length}")
        Dim result((hexString.Length \ 2) - 1) As Byte
        Dim readIndex As Int32 = 0
        Dim readIndexMax As Int32 = hexString.Length - 2
        Dim writeIndex As Int32 = 0
        Dim hexChar As String = Nothing
        Try
            Do While (readIndex <= readIndexMax)
                hexChar = hexString.Substring(readIndex, 2)
                result(writeIndex) = Convert.ToByte(hexChar, 16)
                readIndex += 2
                writeIndex += 1
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException($"Invalid hex string at index {readIndex} ('{hexChar}')!")
        End Try
        Return result
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Crc32

    Private Shared ReadOnly _Table As UInt32()

    Shared Sub New()
        Dim poly As UInt32 = &HEDB88320UI
        _Table = New UInt32(255) {}
        For i As Int32 = 0 To _Table.Length - 1
            Dim temp As UInt32 = CUInt(i)
            For j As Int32 = 8 To 1 Step -1
                If (temp And 1) = 1 Then
                    temp = (temp >> 1) Xor poly
                Else
                    temp >>= 1
                End If
            Next
            _Table(i) = temp
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ComputeChecksum(bytes As Byte()) As UInt32
        Dim crc As UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFFUI
        For i As Int32 = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
            Dim index As Byte = CByte((crc And &HFF) Xor bytes(i))
            crc = CUInt((crc >> 8) Xor _Table(index))
        Next
        Return Not crc
    End Function

End Class
```

I also slightly optimized the Crc32 code to have less casts...

Comment: (As of .NET 5, you can use [`Convert.FromHexString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.fromhexstring) instead of your `ToByteArray` function.)

Comment: OMG! thanks so much for this info. I was trying to change what I was sending to the Crc32 to the right format but nothing I tried worked, I just don't have the knowledge.
Thanks to you both for taking the time to help me :-)